# How to access content of shadow dom with cheerio

Tags: javascript, http, axios, cheerio

When doing a GET request using axios I retrieve the following HTML body:

```
request:
   axios.get(URL)
        .then((response) => result = response.data)

body of 'result':
   <body>
       <custom-component></custom-component>
   </body>
```

When inspecting `custom-component` through Chrome, I can see there are a lot of children which I would like to access.

For example:

```
<custom-component>
   <div class="header-container">...</div>
</custom-component>
```

Typically with cheerio I am able to access that content with:

```
const $ = await cheerio.load(result);
$('.header-container')
```

However, since it is a shadow component, the code above does not work.

Is there any workaround to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You should use puppeteer library to grab something created at runtime.
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/858#issuecomment-441429302